# HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition) renders extremely slowly

Tags: react-native, here-api

I started integrating HERE turn-by-turn navigation into a React Native app using the HERE SDK for Android (Premium Edition) version 3.13.3. The map view is extremely slow and sluggish although the reported rendering time is mostly between 20 and 30 ms. Using the HERE SDK Lite Edition version 4.1.4.0, the map view is snappy.

I am using a Freemium account. Could this explain the slow rendering?

App specs:

- React Native 0.60.4
- Android compile and target SDKs 28

Test device: Xiaomi Redmi Note 7

Comment: Freemium and Premium plans only differ in their way of billing and partially which services are enabled for you. For TbT guidance you would anyway need to upgrade to premium. But as said, it will not have impact on the problems you have already now with mapview. About the different SDK versions: the SDKs are not comparable, since it's a complete redevelopment and new technology stack that comes with 4.x, including a complete new renderer. Since you want to use TbT guidance, there is sadly no premium variant of 4.x yet (only lite/starter is released at this moment).

Comment: Did you try also a native Android app (e.g. the minimal mapview example) on the device ? Is that sluggish too ?

Comment: I implemented a minimal native Android app and it works perfectly. What's interesting about the React Native app is that the map renderer only seems to render exactly once per second. Is that something the HERE devs could look into?

Answer (score 2):

I was eventually able to get the HERE Premium Android SDK running with React-Native at a proper framerate. The important thing is to use the AndroidXMapFragment in the view's layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        class="com.here.android.mpa.mapping.AndroidXMapFragment"
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

and to inflate it in the view using an activity reference that I passed to the view's constructor:

```
mapLayout = (FrameLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_layout, null);
```

Afterwards, the map fragment can be fetched and initialized:

```
mapFragment = (AndroidXMapFragment) activity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
```

Answer (score 0):

In general the HERE Mobile SDK does not support or provide the React framework bindings, hence the responsiveness could be variable. The plans do not have an impact on responsiveness as already mentioned in the comments above

There are some independent developer who have implemented a react component with the SDK, maybe this could be of help : https://github.com/Weopt/react-native-here-maps